# Heroku Travis Build load error. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, travis-ci

My Travis Build was successful. But when I load the app from the browser, heroku shows Application Error.

**Travis Build**

> https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166451784

**heroku logs --app lawvile**

```
F:\Rails Programs\RubymineProjects\LawVille>heroku logs --app lawville
2016-10-10T13:28:28.725622+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T13:47:23.175281+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:23.175368+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:24.126291+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-sinuous-51843) by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:24.126417+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:24.715939+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:24.716704+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a6f7b39 by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:24.716847+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T13:47:25.285374+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T13:47:25.285379+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-10T13:47:27.802081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8451 -e production`
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172158+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172172+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172173+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172174+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172174+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172174+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172175+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172176+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172176+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.172176+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T13:47:31.285208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-10T13:47:31.286679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-10T13:47:31.270532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-10T13:47:34.707070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 30791 -e production`
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135036+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135066+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135073+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135080+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135083+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.135084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T13:47:40.581782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-10T13:47:40.523847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-10T13:47:49.037500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=1e993101-c9f7-4649-9fb0-9f7f297c3000
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:47:56.280283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=701fe1f5-2cfa-491b-b1e4-b6
3f514445fb fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:49:39.078513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=12ae837a-957c-4b21-8d76-144828d3e788
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:49:40.379397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=88906a89-dce9-4cb5-bab5-9f
c6f7c522b8 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:51:02.284694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=356d4532-bebc-44f7-bdbd-5f7b7f3d30fb
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:51:03.727018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=accd4761-4efd-4e3a-9caa-07
5cf21f3b3c fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:53:24.881077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/admin" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=7ff2c2d6-12bd-4772-9f18-5dcfdd45
1adc fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T13:53:26.085156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=477835f2-a354-4ca1-82ad-c1
1265b232bb fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T14:15:49.417252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=a52a5cb1-7b0b-4d96-b627-147b6949f035
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T14:15:50.565853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=2e1a8463-85e0-4df0-b933-5f
f7a58ceda3 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T14:20:23.198506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-10T14:20:26.091969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19883 -e production`
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708894+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708934+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708936+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.708940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T14:20:28.797167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-10T14:20:28.783943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-10T15:03:48.225803+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5e3acd3 by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T15:03:48.225803+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by contact@afolabiolaoluwa.com
2016-10-10T15:03:48.465261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-10T15:03:48.438793+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T15:03:48.438798+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-10T15:03:52.227531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46060 -e production`
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374104+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374126+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374127+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374128+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374129+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374130+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374130+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374131+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374132+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.374132+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T15:03:55.483980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-10T15:03:55.485324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-10T15:03:55.503567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-10T15:03:58.599659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3992 -e production`
2016-10-10T15:04:01.693779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587233+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587250+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587251+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.587254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T15:04:01.692135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-10T15:04:57.570883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=296f103c-4bbc-40fb-9187-2b466ec97292
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:04:58.472841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=3c30ed34-757b-4594-bcf9-53
ac69eef483 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:05:24.060431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=b0a95910-c54f-4023-bd9d-e7266cd4ccf1
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:05:25.371272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=1d3d9983-fa96-47e9-8238-29
9c9d90d0a4 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:07:05.952715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=1c8113ee-d970-44f5-bc43-4d85d27d6d86
fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:07:07.727414+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=7d3c2b8b-7dfb-4e91-89b3-a2
1ed5665c27 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:19:03.796054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=46e5264e-3cb3-4853-abc9-
1d592eb36303 fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-10T15:19:05.218416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawville.herokuapp.com request_id=e05d5500-1fec-43d3-a2c7-37
59166d412c fwd="41.190.3.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'lawville.ca' }
end
```

Reproducing the error, I figured out the error is with Devise--Heroku.

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- devise

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the Devise gem available in production?

Comment: @Kelseydh, How do I test if its available in production?